# How to create a cloud9 SSH workspace with dreamhost VPS

Tags: ssh, dreamhost, cloud9-ide

I have already installed node.js(v0.10.30) and npm. I'm able to establish a SSH connection between my mac and dreamhost VPS via terminal, but i cant do it in Cloud9. Someone help me, please?

Comment: What error do you get? Did you try using the instrcutions here? https://github.com/c9/install

Answer (score 1):

`./server.js -p 8080 -l 0.0.0.0 -a :`


`--settings       Settings file to use
--help           Show command line options.
-t               Start in test mode
-k               Kill tmux server in test mode
-b               Start the bridge server - to receive commands from the cli  [default: false]
-w               Workspace directory
--port           Port
--debug          Turn debugging on
--listen         IP address of the server
--readonly       Run in read only mode
--packed         Whether to use the packed version.
--auth           Basic Auth username:password
--collab         Whether to enable collab.
--no-cache       Don't use the cached version of CSS`

So you can use your own VPS,just change 0.0.0.0 to your server ip.